# I18n URL in Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, customlabel

Using `CustomLabel`s, we are able to use the `{!format($Label.myNamespace.myLabelName, v.myAttribute}` in lightning component markup where `$Label.myNamespace.myLabelName` looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomLabels xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <labels>
    <fullName>myLabelName</fullName>
    <language>en_US</language>
    <protected>true</protected>
    <shortDescription>my label</shortDescription>
    <value>Label text with a parameter {0}</value>
  </labels>
</CustomLabels>
```

This works well for simple string values.

However, in the case of a link that looks like

```
Click <a href="http://example.com">here</a>!
```

how would we pass the anchor tag into the `format` function, or more generally, how do we handle internationalization (i18n) properly in lightning components with link text? other I18n frameworks outside of Salesforce have allowed passing in component markup as a parameter.

the two requirements would be

1. changing the custom label for a different translation should not break the link (as long as the parameter `{0}` is maintained
2. translators looking at the custom labels should understand that the link parameter `{0}` can be moved around in the markup to satisfy different grammatical language needs

if anyone has solved this issue already, would greatly appreciate some pointers towards a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizing details found in generating dyanamic components, I was able to do a very complex implementation that satisfies the above requirements:

**I18nLink.cmp**

```
<aura:component>
  <aura:attribute name="customLabelMessage" type="String" />
  <aura:attribute name="customLabelLinkText" type="String" />
  <aura:attribute name="url" type="String" />
  <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
  {!v.body}
</aura:component>
```

**I18nLinkController.js**

```
({
  doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.doInit(component);
  }
})
```

**I18nLinkHelper.js**

```
({
  doInit: function (component) {
    var componentDefinitions = [];
    var labelToTranslate = component.get('v.customLabelMessage');
    var parameterSyntaxToFind = '{0}';
    var indexOfLink = labelToTranslate.indexOf(parameterSyntaxToFind);
    if (indexOfLink > 0) {
      componentDefinitions.push(['lightning:formattedText', {
        value: labelToTranslate.substring(0, indexOfLink)
      }]);
    }
    componentDefinitions.push(['lightning:formattedUrl', {
      label: component.get('v.customLabelLinkText'),
      value: component.get('v.url')
    }]);
    if (indexOfLink < labelToTranslate.length - parameterSyntaxToFind.length) {
      componentDefinitions.push(['lightning:formattedText', {
        value: labelToTranslate.substring(indexOfLink + parameterSyntaxToFind.length)
      }]);
    }
    $A.createComponents(componentDefinitions, function (components, status, errorMessage) {
      if (status === 'SUCCESS') {
        var parentComponent = component.get('v.body');
        components.forEach(function (dynamicComponent) {
          parentComponent.push(dynamicComponent);
        });
        component.set('v.body', parentComponent);
      } else if (status === 'INCOMPLETE' || status === 'ERROR') {
        // do what you need to do
        // console.error(errorMessage);
      }
    });
  }
})
```

**example usage**

```
<myNamespace:I18nLink
  customLabelMessage="{!$Label.myNamespace.myMessage}"
  customLabelLinkText="{!$Label.myNamespace.myLinkText}"
  url="https://example.com"
/>
```

**CustomLabels.labels-meta.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomLabels xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <labels>
    <fullName>myMessage</fullName>
    <language>en_US</language>
    <protected>true</protected>
    <shortDescription>message containing a link parameter from myLinkText</shortDescription>
    <value>Click {0}!</value>
  </labels>
  <labels>
    <fullName>myLinkText</fullName>
    <language>en_US</language>
    <protected>true</protected>
    <shortDescription>link text used in myMessage</shortDescription>
    <value>here</value>
  </labels>
</CustomLabels>
```